# Style table in repeater from code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hey guys I need some help with an application that I'm developing.

I'm trying to add a css class / styling to a table depending on a certain value that I'm getting from the database ( e.g. 0 - 2).

This is the code where I need to change the styling of the table

```
Public Function projectType(ByVal value As Integer)
  Dim projectName As String
  If value = 0 Then
    projectName = "Project"
    mytable.AddAttributes("Style", "Background-color:#444444")  
  ElseIf value = 1 Then
    projectName = "Support"
  Else
    projectName = "Not available"
  End If
  Return projectName
End Function
```

Markup:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" RepeatColumns="1"
                RepeatDirection="Vertical" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0">
                <ItemTemplate>
                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
                    padding-bottom: 15px;">
                    <tr>
                      <td style="width: 110px; vertical-align: top; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 5px;
                        padding-bottom: 5px;">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# projectType(Eval("Type")) %>' Font-Names="Verdana"
                          Font-Size="9pt" EnableTheming="false" />
                      </td>
                      <td style="width: 110px; vertical-align: top; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 5px;
                        padding-bottom: 5px;">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# hoursCheck(Eval("Duration")) %>'
                          Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9pt" Style="text-align: right" EnableTheming="false" />
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="2" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 5px; text-align: center">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FullName") %>' Font-Names="Verdana"
                          Font-Size="7pt" EnableTheming="false" />
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:DataList>
```

From this function I need to access the table by getting the parent table of the sender since I can't explicitly say I want Datalist1 since I have 5 of them, how can I do this?

Comment: Question definitely needs more data. What is the table, what is the sender? Any relevant page markup?

Comment: @Andrei edited with some markup and more information.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please get rid of inline styles and replace them with CSS classes. Will save you a lot of headache later on. For instance, have two CSS classes, one for "Project", another for "Support" and "Not available"

As for the actual question, the easiest thing that comes to mind is to split the logic into two functions, one for text and one for css class:

```
Public Function projectTypeText(ByVal value As Integer)
    ...
    Return projectName
End Function

Public Function projectTypeClass(ByVal value As Integer)
    ...
    Return projectCssClass
End Function
```

And then use it exactly as you did:

```
<%-- This might actually need runat="server", not sure --%>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style='<%# projectTypeClass(Eval("Type")) %>'

<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# projectType(Eval("Type")) %>'
```

Note: if you absolutely have to deal with inline classes, you can have `projectTypeStyle` which returns `Background-color:#444444`, but then inside the markup you will need to do nasty stuff like that:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style='<%# "width: 100%; rest of styles; " + projectTypeStyle(Eval("Type")) %>'
```

This is horrible, so please avoid at all cost.